# Не применяется позиционирование для кнопки меню.

Tags: html, css

Не могу применить `position: relative` для `<span class = "humb">`.

Пробовал по разному, абсолютное позиционирование задать получается, а при relative элемент исчезает.

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1920px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.head {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.head .header {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.head .header .nav ul {
  display: none;
}

.head .header .nav .humb {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<section class="head">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header class="header">
      <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>
      <nav class="nav">
        <span class="humb"></span>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">fdsf</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">fdsfsda</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">dsa</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">das</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">da</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`span` - по умолчанию `display: inline;`

добавьте для `.humb` - `display: block` или `display: inine-block;`

Comment: soledar10 верно пишет...

Comment: спасибо, дело в том, что до этого делал по тому же принципу без препроцессоров и все работало ок сразу. А тут беда..

Comment: Может использовался float для .hamb - тогда элемент становиться блочным, аналогично с position: absolute; или использовать button